# How do I get a graph to show in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, plotly

I am looking to add a graph to one of my kivy screen app.  Basic App with a StartScreen and the SecondScreen with the graph itself and few buttons.  I can't get the graph to show in Kivy.  I've tried creating a class for it but I always end up getting this error:

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'

I have tried finding the answer by myself but I always get to an dead end. Here is the code for the graph below as well as the code for my app.  If someone could point me in the right direction you would be my HERO!

Yours truly, the coding newbie!

**Here is the graph:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+gauge+delta",
    gauge = {'shape': "bullet"},
    delta = {'reference': 300},
    value = 220,
    domain = {'x': [0.1, 1], 'y': [0.2, 0.9]},
    title = {'text': "Avg order size"}))

fig.show()
```

**Here is my main.py:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass


Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class GraphScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        # Get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

**Here is my main.kv:**

```
#:include kv/startscreen.kv
#:include kv/graphscreen.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        StartScreen:
            name: "start_screen"
            id: start_screen
        GraphScreen:
            name: "graph_screen"
            id: graph_screen
```

**Here is my startscreen.kv:**

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<StartScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Label:
                rows: 1
                text: "Budget Meter"
                font_size: 30
                font_name: "font/Duldolar.ttf"
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            pos_hint: {'x':.02, 'y':.6}
            size_hint: 1, .1
            ImageButton:
                source: "images/Ecommerce_203.jpg"
                on_release:
                    app.change_screen("graph_screen")
```

**Here is my graphscreen.kv:**

```
#:import utils kivy.utils

<GraphScreen>:


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: .3, .5
        pos_hint: {'x':.35, 'y':0}
        ImageButton:
            source: "images/ope.jpg"
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("start_screen")
```

Comment: You could use `fig.write_image()` to save the plot to a file, then use that file as `source` for an `Image` widget.

Comment: With this solution though, would user be able to imput their own data and see the graph's update?

Comment: Yes, you could either write each plot to the same file (over-writing each time) and use the `Image.reload()` method to load the changed image. Or you could write every plot image to a new file, and use the `Image.source` property to get the new image. Note that there will be a little delay between `fig.write_image()` command and the update appearing in the `Image` due to writing/reading a file.